# Input field becomes bigger when selected

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

Could you guys look at site I am working on and help me a little bit with this [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) library and CSS - click at the search field in the bottom of [Telefacer.com](http://Telefacer.com) and you will see that the whole bottom bar slightly shiftes up. I'm unable to fix that by myself T_T.

Comment: The font looks the same to me. what do you mean by bold here? Is it because the search bar is shifted up?

Comment: @iCezz yep, exactly. Gonna change my post to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. If you look at this

```
<ul class="select2-choices">  
     <li class="select2-search-field">    
          <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="select2-input select2-default" tabindex="-1" id="s2id_autogen2" style="width: 496px;">  
     </li>
</ul>
```

when you click or trying to search, there will be additional class and thus it will change the css or have another latest effect, all you have to do is to changea class in your select2.css file

Change the class of

```
.select2-container-active{
    border: 0px solid #5897fb;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

It is due to the border become 1px that's why it shifted up a little bit.

Alternatively: If you don't want to change the css file, what you can do is add a border:0px solid #5897fb; in the ul

```
<ul class="select2-choices" style="border:0px solid #5897fb;">
```

Hope this will solve your problem. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll accept it after I will have time to check.

Comment: Its my pleasure to help. If you have any further concern, feel free to let me know.